# When rotate the landscape to portrait in fragment UI is not refreshing

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I rotate the device landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape device is not refreshing the UI. I’m using fragment "onCreateView" and "onConfigurationChanged" to draw the layout also remote_gesture and remote_navigation have two layout for portrait and landscape. Final added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` to AndroidManifest.xml

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    //View rootView = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_navigation, container, false);

    View rootView = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote, container, false);
    viewSwitcher =(ViewSwitcher)rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_viewswitcher);
    remoteGesture = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_gesture, null);
    remoteNav = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_navigation, null);
    viewSwitcher.addView(remoteNav);
    viewSwitcher.addView(remoteGesture);
    setupButtons(rootView);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {


    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Log.w(TAG, "rrr... onConfigurationChanged...");
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) getView();
    //container.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rootView = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote, container, false);
    viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) rootView.findViewById(R.id.remote_viewswitcher);
    remoteGesture = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_gesture, null);
    remoteNav = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_navigation, null);
    viewSwitcher.addView(remoteNav);
    viewSwitcher.addView(remoteGesture);
}
```

How can I fixed this problem?

Answer (score 1):

On `onConfigurationChanged`(), remove the Views *before adding the new ones*. It's like force refresh. Sample code:

```
viewSwitcher.removeAllViews()
```

Definition of the method @ [ViewGroup removeAllViews()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews())

Another similar sample code, generic version:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

   // Refresh views by removing first
   ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView(); 
   viewGroup.removeAllViewsInLayout();
   ...
}
```

Comment: but this is not redrawing the layout but only removing it.

Comment: @user3480706, If you want to remove only, then don't call addView(). But in your post, it says you want to refresh the UI. So I am saying to remove existing views, then Add them.

Comment: I only did uncomment the line container.removeAllViewsInLayout(); and run the code but it is not refresh the UI can give me steps ?

Comment: @user3480706, I never have used ViewSwitcher. In your case, I think you need to call viewSwitcher.removeAllViews() instead since viewSwitcher is the View object that adds the views.